# Testing different file read methods in Java

Tags: java, profiling, benchmarking, nio, memory-mapped-files

I'm doing a little bit of algorithm profiling, and I've decided to test three file read methods, and then benchmark them (compare their average execution times). First I generate a larde text file (several hundred MBs), and then run ten tests for each method - buffered reader, normal IO read, and memory mapped reading:

```
public static void bufferedRead(String filename) {
    BufferedReader br = null;

    try {
        String sCurrentLine;
        br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(filename));
        while ((sCurrentLine = br.readLine()) != null) {
            System.out.println(sCurrentLine);
        }
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } finally {
        try {
            if (br != null)
                br.close();
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}

public static void NIORead(String filename) throws IOException {
    RandomAccessFile aFile = new RandomAccessFile(filename, "r");
    FileChannel inChannel = aFile.getChannel();
    ByteBuffer buffer = ByteBuffer.allocate(1024);
    while (inChannel.read(buffer) > 0) {
        buffer.flip();
        for (int i = 0; i < buffer.limit(); i++) {
            System.out.print((char) buffer.get());
        }
        buffer.clear(); 
    }
    inChannel.close();
    aFile.close();

}

public static void memoryMapRead(String filename) throws IOException {
    RandomAccessFile aFile = new RandomAccessFile(filename, "r");
    FileChannel inChannel = aFile.getChannel();
    MappedByteBuffer buffer = inChannel.map(FileChannel.MapMode.READ_ONLY,
            0, inChannel.size());
    buffer.load();
    for (int i = 0; i < buffer.limit(); i++) {
        System.out.print((char) buffer.get());
    }
    buffer.clear(); 
    inChannel.close();
    aFile.close();
}
```

However, the entire process (3x10 measurements) takes a really long time, like 9 hours or so. True, I don't have a SSD disk, but still, it seems really long to me, even for a 400 MB text file. My question is: are those time results plausible? If not, is there anything that looks incorrect in those implementations?

Comment: I would **strongly** recommend you use [`Files.lines()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/nio/file/Files.html#lines-java.nio.file.Path-) and forget all this silliness. The bottleneck on any file reading will be the IO, not the code. Also, please learn to use `try-with-resources` to guarantee that your resources are closed correctly.

Comment: Have you tried removing `System.out.println`? Printing stuff to console (especially if all other operations are fast) can significantly slow down your porgram.

Comment: @Turing85 irrelevant. The constraining factor will be the disc IO here.

Comment: So is it solely a matter of my hard disk?

Comment: _Anything_ in memory will be faster than your hard disk. Use the correct method for reading what you need to read, but as I said, `Files.lines` is correct for most everything.

Comment: Yes, but I'm not looking for the fastest method. I want to test those three specifically, and not other. I just wanted to make sure these are the optimum implementations of buffered reading, native IO, and memory mapped reading.

Comment: NIO doesn't stand for `native` IO, it stands for **new** IO. Both the `BufferedReader` and `NIO` methods are entirely pointless - use `Files.lines`. Your mapped method is also entirely pointless, mapping is for optimising random access to a file by mapping it to a region of memory; what you have done serves no purpose at all. As I said, use `Files.lines` and forget this silliness.

Comment: But use `Files.lines` in place of what? Where exactly?

Comment: And as far as optimum implementation goes - you don't use `try-with-resources` and all the methods do is print to STDOUT which makes them next to useless in any other context.

Comment: `Files.lines` in place of **everything**!

Comment: But I've said several times:  I need to compare those three methods. If they exist in Java, there surely has to be a way to implement them all in  a correct way, while still using three DISTINCT ways of file access.

Comment: The're **old**, **new** IO is called **new** IO because it's replacing the `java.io.File`. `NIO.2` is called `NIO.2` because it replaces NIO. The only reason to carry on using the old APIs is for compatibility with existing code - and even then, there's a lot in place to help interoperate with the old APIs. **Just because it's there doesn't mean it should be used**.

Comment: But I'm not asking whether or not I SHOULD use them. Please read again what my question is, and if you can, answer that and only that question.

Comment: Your question makes no sense. I have answered it with advice on what you should do. If you don't want to do that, then fine. No skin off my back.

Comment: How can it make no sense? You're saying, that there exists no correct implementation of buffered reader for example?

Comment: If I'm saying, that I'd like to compare three different file access methods, and you propose to use `Files.lines` for each of them, what am I comparing then exactly?

Comment: @MichałSzydłowski  do not see a problem with your code. And to the both of you: `nio` does neither stand for "native" nor for "new". It is [non-blocking](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/channels/package-summary.html#multiplex)

Comment: @Turing85 In any case, removing console printing did help a LOT. Thank you!

Comment: @MichałSzydłowski i will post it as an answer, if this is fine by you.

Comment: Absolutely, please do

Comment: @Turing85 [_and sometimes called "New I/O"_](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Non-blocking_I/O_(Java)). And in this usage it is most definitely _blocking_...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Removing `System.out.println(...)` may improve the performance of your benchmark, but make sure to do something with the read `String`, so the loops do not get optimized out.